# Correct EventStore config for a 3 node cluster?

Tags: configuration, cluster-computing, eventstoredb

So I had EventStore 5.0.7 installed as a 3 node cluster, working just fine.

I tried to upgrade to EventStore 21.10.1. The config for EventStore has changed substantially since the move from 5.x to 20.x and 21.x, and despite multiple readings of all kinds of documentation, I'm still doing something wrong.

What we see is 6 nodes appearing - each server twice - and the gossip failing, and nothing working, ie, cannot insert events.

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**EventStore 5.0.7**

[image: EventStore 5.0.7]

**EventStore 21.10.1**

[image: EventStore 21.10.1]

**Config for EventStore 21.10.1**

```
---
# Paths
Db: /var/lib/eventstore
Index: /var/lib/eventstore/index
Log: /var/log/eventstore

# Run in insecure mode
Insecure: true
DisableInternalTcpTls: true
DisableExternalTcpTls: true

# Network configuration
IntIp: 172.31.47.243
ExtIp: 0.0.0.0
HttpPort: 2113
IntTcpPort: 1112
ExtTcpPort: 1113
EnableExternalTcp: true
EnableAtomPubOverHTTP: false

# Projections configuration
RunProjections: System
ClusterSize: 3

LogLevel: Verbose
LogHttpRequests: true
LogFailedAuthenticationAttempts: true
LogConfig: /etc/eventstore/logconfig.json

HttpPortAdvertiseAs: 2114
ExtHostAdvertiseAs: 54.209.234.141

IntTcpHeartbeatTimeout: 2000
ExtTcpHeartbeatTimeout: 2000
IntTcpHeartbeatInterval: 5000
ExtTcpHeartbeatInterval: 5000
GossipTimeoutMs: 5000
GossipIntervalMs: 2000

StatsPeriodSec: 900

DiscoverViaDns: false
GossipSeed: 172.31.45.192:2113,172.31.41.141:2113
```

---

**Config for EventStore 21.10.1 (as seen at startup)**

```
MODIFIED OPTIONS:

     STATS PERIOD SEC:                        900 (Yaml)
     LOG HTTP REQUESTS:                       true (Yaml)
     LOG FAILED AUTHENTICATION ATTEMPTS:      true (Yaml)
     INSECURE:                                true (Yaml)
     LOG:                                     /var/log/eventstore (Yaml)
     LOG CONFIG:                              /etc/eventstore/logconfig.json (Yaml)
     LOG LEVEL:                               Verbose (Yaml)
     CLUSTER SIZE:                            3 (Yaml)
     DISCOVER VIA DNS:                        false (Yaml)
     GOSSIP SEED:                             172.31.46.96:2113,172.31.40.110:2113 (Yaml)
     GOSSIP INTERVAL MS:                      2000 (Yaml)
     GOSSIP TIMEOUT MS:                       5000 (Yaml)
     DB:                                      /var/lib/eventstore (Yaml)
     INDEX:                                   /var/lib/eventstore/index (Yaml)
     INT IP:                                  172.31.35.133 (Yaml)
     EXT IP:                                  0.0.0.0 (Yaml)
     HTTP PORT:                               2113 (Yaml)
     ENABLE EXTERNAL TCP:                     true (Yaml)
     INT TCP PORT:                            1112 (Yaml)
     EXT TCP PORT:                            1113 (Yaml)
     EXT HOST ADVERTISE AS:                   3.82.200.231 (Yaml)
     HTTP PORT ADVERTISE AS:                  2114 (Yaml)
     INT TCP HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT:               2000 (Yaml)
     EXT TCP HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT:               2000 (Yaml)
     INT TCP HEARTBEAT INTERVAL:              5000 (Yaml)
     EXT TCP HEARTBEAT INTERVAL:              5000 (Yaml)
     DISABLE INTERNAL TCP TLS:                true (Yaml)
     DISABLE EXTERNAL TCP TLS:                true (Yaml)
     ENABLE ATOM PUB OVER HTTP:               false (Yaml)
     RUN PROJECTIONS:                         System (Yaml)

DEFAULT OPTIONS:

     HELP:                                    False (<DEFAULT>)
     VERSION:                                 False (<DEFAULT>)
     CONFIG:                                  /etc/eventstore/eventstore.conf (<DEFAULT>)
     WHAT IF:                                 False (<DEFAULT>)
     START STANDARD PROJECTIONS:              False (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE HTTP CACHING:                    False (<DEFAULT>)
     WORKER THREADS:                          0 (<DEFAULT>)
     ENABLE HISTOGRAMS:                       False (<DEFAULT>)
     SKIP INDEX SCAN ON READS:                False (<DEFAULT>)
     MAX APPEND SIZE:                         1048576 (<DEFAULT>)
     LOG CONSOLE FORMAT:                      Plain (<DEFAULT>)
     LOG FILE SIZE:                           1073741824 (<DEFAULT>)
     LOG FILE INTERVAL:                       Day (<DEFAULT>)
     LOG FILE RETENTION COUNT:                31 (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE LOG FILE:                        False (<DEFAULT>)
     AUTHORIZATION TYPE:                      internal (<DEFAULT>)
     AUTHORIZATION CONFIG:                    <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     AUTHENTICATION TYPE:                     internal (<DEFAULT>)
     AUTHENTICATION CONFIG:                   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE FIRST LEVEL HTTP AUTHORIZATION:  False (<DEFAULT>)
     TRUSTED ROOT CERTIFICATES PATH:          <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE RESERVED NODE COMMON NAME:   eventstoredb-node (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE FILE:                        <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE PRIVATE KEY FILE:            <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE PASSWORD:                    <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE STORE LOCATION:              <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE STORE NAME:                  <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE SUBJECT NAME:                <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT:                  <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     STREAM INFO CACHE CAPACITY:              0 (<DEFAULT>)
     NODE PRIORITY:                           0 (<DEFAULT>)
     COMMIT COUNT:                            -1 (<DEFAULT>)
     PREPARE COUNT:                           -1 (<DEFAULT>)
     CLUSTER DNS:                             fake.dns (<DEFAULT>)
     CLUSTER GOSSIP PORT:                     2113 (<DEFAULT>)
     GOSSIP ALLOWED DIFFERENCE MS:            60000 (<DEFAULT>)
     READ ONLY REPLICA:                       False (<DEFAULT>)
     UNSAFE ALLOW SURPLUS NODES:              False (<DEFAULT>)
     DEAD MEMBER REMOVAL PERIOD SEC:          1800 (<DEFAULT>)
     LEADER ELECTION TIMEOUT MS:              1000 (<DEFAULT>)
     QUORUM SIZE:                             1 (<DEFAULT>)
     PREPARE ACK COUNT:                       1 (<DEFAULT>)
     COMMIT ACK COUNT:                        1 (<DEFAULT>)
     MIN FLUSH DELAY MS:                      2 (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE SCAVENGE MERGING:                False (<DEFAULT>)
     SCAVENGE HISTORY MAX AGE:                30 (<DEFAULT>)
     CACHED CHUNKS:                           -1 (<DEFAULT>)
     CHUNKS CACHE SIZE:                       536871424 (<DEFAULT>)
     MAX MEM TABLE SIZE:                      1000000 (<DEFAULT>)
     HASH COLLISION READ LIMIT:               100 (<DEFAULT>)
     MEM DB:                                  False (<DEFAULT>)
     USE INDEX BLOOM FILTERS:                 True (<DEFAULT>)
     INDEX CACHE SIZE:                        0 (<DEFAULT>)
     SKIP DB VERIFY:                          False (<DEFAULT>)
     WRITE THROUGH:                           False (<DEFAULT>)
     UNBUFFERED:                              False (<DEFAULT>)
     CHUNK INITIAL READER COUNT:              5 (<DEFAULT>)
     PREPARE TIMEOUT MS:                      2000 (<DEFAULT>)
     COMMIT TIMEOUT MS:                       2000 (<DEFAULT>)
     WRITE TIMEOUT MS:                        2000 (<DEFAULT>)
     UNSAFE DISABLE FLUSH TO DISK:            False (<DEFAULT>)
     UNSAFE IGNORE HARD DELETE:               False (<DEFAULT>)
     SKIP INDEX VERIFY:                       False (<DEFAULT>)
     INDEX CACHE DEPTH:                       16 (<DEFAULT>)
     OPTIMIZE INDEX MERGE:                    False (<DEFAULT>)
     ALWAYS KEEP SCAVENGED:                   False (<DEFAULT>)
     REDUCE FILE CACHE PRESSURE:              False (<DEFAULT>)
     INITIALIZATION THREADS:                  1 (<DEFAULT>)
     READER THREADS COUNT:                    0 (<DEFAULT>)
     MAX AUTO MERGE INDEX LEVEL:              2147483647 (<DEFAULT>)
     WRITE STATS TO DB:                       False (<DEFAULT>)
     MAX TRUNCATION:                          268435456 (<DEFAULT>)
     CHUNK SIZE:                              268435456 (<DEFAULT>)
     STATS STORAGE:                           File (<DEFAULT>)
     DB LOG FORMAT:                           V2 (<DEFAULT>)
     STREAM EXISTENCE FILTER SIZE:            256000000 (<DEFAULT>)
     KEEP ALIVE INTERVAL:                     10000 (<DEFAULT>)
     KEEP ALIVE TIMEOUT:                      10000 (<DEFAULT>)
     INT HOST ADVERTISE AS:                   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     ADVERTISE HOST TO CLIENT AS:             <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     ADVERTISE HTTP PORT TO CLIENT AS:        0 (<DEFAULT>)
     ADVERTISE TCP PORT TO CLIENT AS:         0 (<DEFAULT>)
     EXT TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS:               0 (<DEFAULT>)
     INT TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS:               0 (<DEFAULT>)
     GOSSIP ON SINGLE NODE:                   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
     CONNECTION PENDING SEND BYTES THRESHOLD: 10485760 (<DEFAULT>)
     CONNECTION QUEUE SIZE THRESHOLD:         50000 (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE ADMIN UI:                        False (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE STATS ON HTTP:                   False (<DEFAULT>)
     DISABLE GOSSIP ON HTTP:                  False (<DEFAULT>)
     ENABLE TRUSTED AUTH:                     False (<DEFAULT>)
     PROJECTION THREADS:                      3 (<DEFAULT>)
     PROJECTIONS QUERY EXPIRY:                5 (<DEFAULT>)
     FAULT OUT OF ORDER PROJECTIONS:          False (<DEFAULT>)
     PROJECTION COMPILATION TIMEOUT:          500 (<DEFAULT>)
     PROJECTION EXECUTION TIMEOUT:            250 (<DEFAULT>)
```

**Gossip for EventStore 21.10.1**

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "instanceId": "ed2ee047-eb59-4b11-86fd-a5b366edd0ce",
      "timeStamp": "2022-01-12T23:17:42.539034Z",
      "state": "Unknown",
      "isAlive": true,
      "internalTcpIp": "172.31.46.231",
      "internalTcpPort": 1112,
      "internalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "externalTcpIp": "52.91.48.59",
      "externalTcpPort": 1113,
      "externalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "httpEndPointIp": "52.91.48.59",
      "httpEndPointPort": 2114,
      "lastCommitPosition": -1,
      "writerCheckpoint": 0,
      "chaserCheckpoint": 0,
      "epochPosition": -1,
      "epochNumber": -1,
      "epochId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "nodePriority": 0,
      "isReadOnlyReplica": false
    },
    {
      "instanceId": "dfcc4139-2966-454c-8cee-71261cedafba",
      "timeStamp": "2022-01-12T23:17:40.0803168Z",
      "state": "Unknown",
      "isAlive": false,
      "internalTcpIp": "172.31.46.43",
      "internalTcpPort": 1112,
      "internalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "externalTcpIp": "44.201.237.180",
      "externalTcpPort": 1113,
      "externalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "httpEndPointIp": "44.201.237.180",
      "httpEndPointPort": 2114,
      "lastCommitPosition": -1,
      "writerCheckpoint": 0,
      "chaserCheckpoint": 0,
      "epochPosition": -1,
      "epochNumber": -1,
      "epochId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "nodePriority": 0,
      "isReadOnlyReplica": false
    },
    {
      "instanceId": "2a47929c-afd6-496f-b87b-d85904eeed18",
      "timeStamp": "2022-01-12T23:17:40.539795Z",
      "state": "Unknown",
      "isAlive": true,
      "internalTcpIp": "172.31.38.246",
      "internalTcpPort": 1112,
      "internalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "externalTcpIp": "3.93.17.39",
      "externalTcpPort": 1113,
      "externalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "httpEndPointIp": "3.93.17.39",
      "httpEndPointPort": 2114,
      "lastCommitPosition": -1,
      "writerCheckpoint": 0,
      "chaserCheckpoint": 0,
      "epochPosition": -1,
      "epochNumber": -1,
      "epochId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "nodePriority": 0,
      "isReadOnlyReplica": false
    },
    {
      "instanceId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "timeStamp": "2022-01-12T22:39:46.4047071Z",
      "state": "Manager",
      "isAlive": true,
      "internalTcpIp": "172.31.46.43",
      "internalTcpPort": 2113,
      "internalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "externalTcpIp": "172.31.46.43",
      "externalTcpPort": 2113,
      "externalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "httpEndPointIp": "172.31.46.43",
      "httpEndPointPort": 2113,
      "lastCommitPosition": -1,
      "writerCheckpoint": -1,
      "chaserCheckpoint": -1,
      "epochPosition": -1,
      "epochNumber": -1,
      "epochId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "nodePriority": 0,
      "isReadOnlyReplica": false
    },
    {
      "instanceId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "timeStamp": "2022-01-12T22:53:47.9621597Z",
      "state": "Manager",
      "isAlive": true,
      "internalTcpIp": "172.31.46.231",
      "internalTcpPort": 2113,
      "internalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "externalTcpIp": "172.31.46.231",
      "externalTcpPort": 2113,
      "externalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "httpEndPointIp": "172.31.46.231",
      "httpEndPointPort": 2113,
      "lastCommitPosition": -1,
      "writerCheckpoint": -1,
      "chaserCheckpoint": -1,
      "epochPosition": -1,
      "epochNumber": -1,
      "epochId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "nodePriority": 0,
      "isReadOnlyReplica": false
    },
    {
      "instanceId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "timeStamp": "2022-01-12T22:53:47.9621597Z",
      "state": "Manager",
      "isAlive": true,
      "internalTcpIp": "172.31.38.246",
      "internalTcpPort": 2113,
      "internalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "externalTcpIp": "172.31.38.246",
      "externalTcpPort": 2113,
      "externalSecureTcpPort": 0,
      "httpEndPointIp": "172.31.38.246",
      "httpEndPointPort": 2113,
      "lastCommitPosition": -1,
      "writerCheckpoint": -1,
      "chaserCheckpoint": -1,
      "epochPosition": -1,
      "epochNumber": -1,
      "epochId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "nodePriority": 0,
      "isReadOnlyReplica": false
    }
  ],
  "serverIp": "52.91.48.59",
  "serverPort": 2114
}
```

Comment: Please post the config file itself, it's easier to understand it compared to the config print-out. Also, it would be nice to know the topology, as your internal and external IPs are different.

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux? because it looks like you have the old windows manager nodes running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This online tool : https://configurator.eventstore.com/ should help you setup the configuration correctly